# Problems installing Windows 10 under VMware Fusion on El Capitan Mac

Tags: macos, windows-10, vmware-fusion, osx-el-capitan

When I try to install Windows 10 under VMware Fusion, it gives an error titled "Load driver" with the message "No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, then click OK."

[image]

This is after downloading a generic Windows 10 x64 ISO from Microsoft, and purchasing a license key for the home edition (but I haven't gotten far enough to enter a purchased home license key).

How can I provide drivers or otherwise pacify Windows 10 so it will install under VMware Fusion?

Thanks,

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @Trip We'll see. It worked and installed, then all my Windows VM's besides XP (and an archaic NT 4.0) went out to lunch. I'm in the process of creating a new Windows 10 VM after every attempt to fix Windows from within, even a complete reinstall from Windows 10, failed to show signs of life.